# Visual studio 2013 ultimate issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-7-x64

I've windows 7 ultimate 64-bit. Is it possible to install visual studio 2013 ultimate. Right now I'mm getting error "The version of Visual studio requires newer version of windows". Kindly reply as early as possible..

[Log file](http://pastebin.com/UeyNmK1q)

Comment: That is for Visual studio Express. But I need to know about Visual studio ULTIMATE on Windows 7 ULTIMATE.

Comment: OK. Do you have SP1 installed on your Win7? (It's indicated as being one of the [minimum system requirements](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-professional-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements).

Comment: No. Ok I'll do one thing I'll start automatic updates and try to download it.